# Is castling allowed in this position?

Tags: castling

```
[FEN "8/8/b7/8/8/8/8/4K2R w - - 0 1 "]
```

In this case White hasn't moved his King yet. Is castling allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to castle, because the `f1` square is attacked.

See the [Laws of Chess](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=124&view=article); article 3.8 (King moves), b(2):

> Castling is prevented temporarily:
>
> - if the square on which the king stands, **or the square which it must cross**, or the square which it is to occupy, is attacked by one or more of the opponent's pieces, or
> - if there is any piece between the king and the rook with which castling is to be effected.